# Is it possible to call a telephone number with an extension?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm writing an iPhone application which needs to have an option to call our office. However, the phone number that needs to be dialed has a 5 digit extension.

I know that to call a regular phone number we can use `openURL` using something like:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
    openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1-800-555-5555"]];
```

Can I get this to work with an extension? If so, how?

The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) link to [RFC 2806](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2806.txt), which describes the URL scheme for `tel:` and it seems as though extensions are supported, but I can't figure out the syntax from the RFC.

Comment: In the GSM world, there is a way to insert a delay into a dialing string.  Sorry, I don't remember it, but it's a place to start.

In your RFC, section 2.5.6 it says "A local phone number or a post-dial sequence may contain <pause-
   character> characters which indicate a pause while dialing ("p"), or
   a wait for dial tone ("w")."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is the answer, but from the RFC you linked on page 14:

> ```
> tel:+358-555-1234567;postd=pp22
> ```
>
> The above URL instructs the local entity to place a voice call to
>    +358-555-1234567, then wait for an implementation-dependent time (for
>    example, two seconds) and emit two DTMF dialing tones "2" on the line
>    (for example, to choose a particular extension number, or to invoke a
>    particular service).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it and didn't need the postd.  I just put the phone number @"800-555-5555;pp1" and it worked like a charm.  Thanks Topher!

Comment: I just tried and it wouldn't work with the semicolon!
@"+1-800-555-5555p1" worked for me though.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a phone system where you dial the main number, hear a prompt and then enter the extension number then you can include a pause in your number to allow for the call to be picked up. Per the RFC 2806 that you linked to this is done using a `"p"` pause character for each 1 second pause.